# Is there an IIS 7.5 Web Site View that looks anything like IIS 6 Web Site Properties?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, website

Is there an IIS 7.5 Web Site View that looks anything like the IIS 6 Web Site Properties view?  I know where everything is in IIS6 (host headers, redirections, default filename etc.), but the view in IIS 7.5 is completely different.  Is there anyway to access a traditional view in IIS 7.5?

If not, how would I access these features in IIS 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. But if you play with it, I think you'll grow to like it (I did).

Host headers: Select Web site > under IIS > HTTP Response Headers
 or under Actions on the right-side > Bindings ...

Redirections: I've always just installed URL Rewrite (via Web Platform Installer) and have used that. Otherwise IIS 7.x writes to Web.config, so you could go that route. [More about HTTP Redirects](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect) - via the interface it requires a feature be turned on, as detailed in the article.

Default filename: Select Web site > under IIS > Default Document

Comment: No problem! And again, I think you'll come to like IIS 7's interface after you play around with it. It takes a bit of time, but it's pretty slick.

Comment: I installed The URL rewrite.  Once I open it for a a Web Site, how would I set it to redirect all requests to http://www.google.com ?

Comment: I've detailed the steps in another answer. I'm not sure if I should have just edited the above answer, but ...

Answer (score 1):

This won't fit as a comment, so to answer your question about redirecting all requests to another domain:

1. Create a new Inbound rule (blank).
2. Give it whatever name you want.
3. Under Match URL select Matches the Pattern and Regular Expressions.
4. Set pattern to `.*`
5. Under Action select a type of Redirect.
6. Enter whatever URL you want under Redirect URL (example: http://www.google.com).
7. Decide whether you want to append the query string or not, and what type of status code you want returned.

Note that if you want to use a canonical domain (so force www.domain.com or domain.com, or even altdomain1.com to go to domain.com) there's some nice templates already created under the SEO heading - Canonical domain name in particular (which I've found very valuable).

EDIT: I suppose you could also add google.com as a domain to the site, and then use the method detailed in http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/30/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one.aspx since it's unlikely google.com would point to your server. However, that smells like a hack to me, so I don't know that I'd recommend it.

Comment: And I believe this assumes URL Redirect 2.0 (which is installed via Web Platform Installer).